# How to convert a CoreML Model to a TensorFlow Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, coreml

I read that it is possible to convert a TensorFlow Model (.pb) file to CoreML (.mlmodel) to run it on iOS platforms. But I have some .mlmodel files that I want to run on tensorflow. So I want to know if there is any way I could convert them to .pb files or any other way I could use them in Tensorflow.

Comment: https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/tensorflow-2 this helps you exchange between tensorflow and coreml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news: Yes, you can do this.

The bad news: You'll have to do it by hand. There are no tools for doing this automatically.

The easiest solution is to define the model in TensorFlow, then copy the weights from the Core ML model into the TF model.

Comment: Any idea how can I get the weights of the Core ML model?

Comment: You load the model with coremltools in a Python script and then step through all the layers by hand to get their weights.

Comment: Could you help me more please, I have no Idea of how I can inspect the model using coremltools, I have searched the internet but found nothing.

Comment: It will be too much work to explain this on StackOverflow, but there are a number of blog posts on my blog that explain how to dig into a model using coremltools, plus I wrote a book that goes into a lot more detail. You can find both links in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools  it supports CoreML conversion